# How to optimize a UDP socket for packet forwarding

Tags: c, sockets, networking, udp

I'm doing packet forwarding through the use of a UDP socket. The setup is based on a traffic generator which sends packets to the UDP socket, the UDP socket then simply switches the source and destination addresses and sends the packet back to the where the packet came from (the traffic generator) where some networking metrics are then recorded.

I have tried to create the simplest application for doing this, which is able to send back about `350 000` packets/second to the traffic generator while the traffic generator is sending about `5 000 000` packets/second to the UDP socket. Therefore, it seems like there should be some room for improvement.

Here is the code for the UDP socket for echoing the packet back.

```
#define PORT 12345
#define IP_ADDR "192.168.0.32"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int socket_fd;
    struct sockaddr_in address, send_address;
    char packet_buffert[2000] = {0};

    if ((socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IP_ADDR);

    if(bind(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&address, sizeof(address))<0){
        return -1;
    }

    socklen_t s = sizeof(send_address);

    while(1){

        if (recvfrom(socket_fd, packet_buffert, sizeof(packet_buffert), 0,(struct sockaddr*)&send_address, (socklen_t*)&s) < 0)
        {
             return -1;
        } 

        if (sendto(socket_fd, packet_buffert, sizeof(packet_buffert), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&send_address, (socklen_t)sizeof(send_address)) < 0)
        {
            return -1;
        }
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

What changes to the UDP socket could be made to improve or optimize the throughput, so that it may achieve higher packets/second? Is there some important concepts that this implementation is missing out on that could improve networking performance?

Thoughts I have had so far has been if and how batching packets could be done. Also I noticed that as the packet buffer is set to `2000` it creates a situation where when the socket receives packets of lets say `64` bytes it sends back packets which are a lot larger than `64` bytes.

Comment: Aside: I strongly doubt you are sending 5 million packets per second from your generator. Even with minimal-sized packets (64 bytes) you'd need over a 3 Gb/s network connection. They are being dropped somewhere.

Comment: Is your generator sending 2000-byte messages?  Because you are sending 2000-byte replies, regardless of the length of the incoming messages.

Comment: *"it creates a situation where when the socket receives packets of lets say 64 bytes it sends back packets which are a lot larger than 64 bytes"* - `recvfrom` gives you how many bytes are received. Use this for the size in `sendto` instead of `sizeof(packet_buffert)`.

Comment: At 5,000,000 64-byte UDP datagrams (not packets; the D in UDP is for Datagram) per second, your sending host is dropping most of them in the internal network interface because your network interface cannot handle that amount of traffic. Remember that UDP is a fire-and-forget protocol where the  application simply sends datagrams, and UDP has no concern that the data are even delivered.

Comment: There's probably little to be gained by trying to optimise your code. I doubt it could be made any faster (once you fix the bugs). You can probably make big gains by properly configuring your network stack. There are lots of resources online, and Linux has a very tune-able network stack. [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) might be a good place to look / ask.

Comment: I'm using XL710 for 40GbE and the environment is on a computer and where it is sending data over an internal virtual network, so I think that it is actually very reasonable. @pmacfarlane

Comment: That's probably information you should have included in your question from the beginning. I'd recommend checking how many UDP packets your Linux machine is receiving first of all, before worrying about how many it can reply to.

Comment: Sure you are correct, but I thought the exact numbers did not matter so much in this question as it has more to do about ideas and solutions for increasing performance of packet handling in general. Server Fault seems like a good place to start looking for ideas. Do you have any suggestion of what I could start looking at? @pmacfarlane

Comment: I should also mention that I am doing bench marking of different frameworks/libraries for packet handling e.g. io_uring. Thus, I am not so interested in fine tuning Linux as I am of just giving each alternative the optimal conditions to perform. @pmacfarlane

Answer (score 0):

Before worrying about optimisations, you should ascertain whether your code is bug-free — which it is not.

```
while(1){

        if (recvfrom(socket_fd, packet_buffert, sizeof(packet_buffert), 0,(struct sockaddr*)&send_address, (socklen_t*)&s) < 0)
        {
             return -1;
        } 

        if (sendto(socket_fd, packet_buffert, sizeof(packet_buffert), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&send_address, (socklen_t)sizeof(send_address)) < 0)
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

> Is your generator sending 2000-byte messages? Because you are sending
> 2000-byte replies, regardless of the length of the incoming messages. – John Bollinger

`recvfrom(2)` returns the number of bytes received; use that as the last argument to `sendto(2)`.

```
for (;;) {
    if ((n = recvfrom (socket_fd, packet_buffert, sizeof packet_buffert, 0,(struct sockaddr*)&send_address, (socklen_t*)&s)) == -1 
        || sendto (socket_fd, packet_buffert, sizeof packet_buffert, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&send_address, n) == -1) {
        /* Perhaps log a message here? */
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated the code to use this instead, which fixed the bug with the size of the packets but the packets/second also decreased from ``350 000` to `270 000`. Any idea why this could be happening?